# How could I make this advantage?

Tags: character-creation, gurps-4e

I have a dimensional character in mind for a GURPS Supers game. One power I have in mind is that the character can go into an alternate dimension that is identical to the original dimension except for that no people exist. So, essentially, he can disappear, walk around, and show up in a different place. How could I do this? Points are not really an object (I have 1000 to play with).

Comment: Which setting are you looking for? Is earlier GURPs material allowed?

Comment: Just how identical is the otherworld? Is it usable for gathering information, as well as transportation?

Comment: @JohnDallman what I had in mind is identical, but objects and stuff that frequently change places would not show up, as their ‘spacial identity’ or whatever would not be strong enough.

Comment: That sounds like... the penumbra from Werewolf the Apocalypse/mage the ascension, just devoid of spirits.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic power is Jumper (World), to your otherworld. That might allow a Limited Access limitation, but that depends on what other worlds exist in your setting. You need plenty of Reliable, so that you don't mess up too often, and probably Extra Carrying Capacity, plus Cannot Escort if the otherworld is meant to be exclusively yours, and Cannot Follow if you can't go to any other worlds.

All those modifiers are on pp. B64-65 and ***Powers***, pp. 57-58.